# How to group objects of one class as an array of objects in another class?

Tags: c++

I've made a class called `Player`, whose goal is to create a new object player that has these attributes as below and vector of 5 strings (skills of player).

```
Player(string name, string surname, int height, vector<string> skills) {
    this->name = name;
    this->surname = surname;
    this->height = height;
    this->skills = skills;
}
```

I've also created a method that shows data of an object.

```
// Method showing data
string show_data() {
    stringstream ss;
    string s;

    ss <<
        this->name << " " <<
        this->surname << " " <<
        this->height << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ss << this->skills[i] << " ";
    }
    ss << "\n";
    s = ss.str();
    return s;
}
```

My goal is to group 5 players into one team in another class. I've printed out the data of players

```
cout << "Liverpool\n" << p1.show_data() << p2.show_data() << p3.show_data() << p4.show_data() << p5.show_data() << endl
```

But I want to have something like
`cout << liverpool.show_data();` and it should print the data of all 5 players

`cout << real_madrit.show_data();` etc..

The question arises, how can I pass these 5 objects to another class with their attributes?

Comment: Create a `Team` class that has a `std::vector<Player>`.

Comment: "how can I pass these 5 objects to another class with their attributes" - put the 5 objects in a container and pass the container.

Comment: Exactly the same way you do it with the player's skills?

Comment: It does seem strange to start with a class (`Player`) that groups 5 objects of a different class (`std::string`), then ask how to define a class that groups 5 objects of a different class. Where's the problem? Did you try it and run into a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a new class that has Players.

```
class Team
{
private:

  std::vector<Player> players_;

public:

  Team(std::vector<Player> p) : players_(p) {}

  void show_data() const
  {
    for (auto const & player : players_)
      std::cout << player.show_data();
  } 
};
```

Now you can use this class like so.

```
std::vector<Player> p = /* create a bunch of players */
Team team(p); // create a Team
team.show_data(); // display the team
```

If you try to compile this example, you will get an error, because each player in the for loop in `Team::show_data()` is marked as a const-reference. You could remove the const here, but don't do that. (After all, showing the data of a Team/Player shouldn't modify the Team/Player). So instead, make your `Player::show_data()` a const method.

Note that this will allow teams of any number of players. If you definitely want just 5 per team, then your `players_` member could be an array

```
std::array<Player, 5> players_;
```

If you see the Team class constructor, you might see the initializer list syntax. You could use that for your Player constructor as well, and it becomes

```
Player(string name, string surname, int height, vector<string> skills) 
 : name(name), surname(surname), height(height), skills(skills) {}
```

Comment: And if it doesn't work its because Player::show_data needs to be const.

Comment: Ok it works :) Thank you very much! 
I have one more question, could you help me with creating copy constructor for class Team?

Comment: @Mefrex The `Team` class presented in this answer shouldn't need a user-defined copy constructor.  The default one will do just fine.

Comment: Alright. In my homework I gotta change one attribute of any player. This task requires not having "const" in my methods. Could you help me rewrite show_data() method in a class Team?

Comment: You want to change a Player attribute inside show_data()? That's not good design, IMO

Comment: No, I've already done a method called change_height within Player class that actually changes the attribute, but it results in not changing the value when it comes to print out the data of the whole team.

Comment: So my question is: can we modify this show_data method to be "changeable"?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what const methods are.  They don't affect whether an object can be changed or not. It only affects whether you can call the method on a const object or not. Perhaps you should ask a new question that describes your issue.